# How to sort stock months using linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, charts

I have some stock data that I'm trying to sort using linq, however I'm very unfamiliar with linq and cannot understand the documentation.

Right now I have a list of bars (a class I've created that holds the stock data) and it's all of the stock data for each day since 1990. Now I'm trying to group this stock data by year and month so I can turn daily stock data into monthly stock data (the resolution of the stock).

```
public class Stock
{
    private string stockSymboll;
    private string period;
    private List<bar> aBar = new List<bar>();
    private DateTime startingDate;
    private DateTime endingDate;
    enum period { DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY };
    private period PeriodType;
}


public class bar
{
    private double open;
    private double high;
    private double low;
    private double close;
    private double volume;
    private DateTime stockDate;
}
```

within the stock class I have a function that I'm trying to use to convert from a list of daily data to a list of monthly data, in order from most recent to least recent.

Here is what I've attempted:

```
stock convertPeriod(Period pt)
{
    stock newStock = new Stock(stockName, startingDate, endingDate, period);
    if (pt == Periode.MONTHLY)
    {
        List<bar> monthlyGroup = new List<bar>();
        var group1 = (from b in bar group c by b.getDate().Month);
        var group2 = from g in group1 group g by g.getDate().Year)
       return...;
    }
}
```

However I've discovered that you cannot sort a var. So I was thinking the best way would be to attempt a nested query in linq, however I can hardly seem to even get basic queries to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what contract you're supposed to be setting up, but as I understand it, you want to:

- Receive an `IEnumerable<Bar>`, and
- Return an `IEnumerable<Bar>` such that `StockDate` is the first day of the year and month for the summarized stocks, all sorted descending by date.

As I understand it, `Stock` is more or less irrelevant to your true question here. If I'm incorrect in that, let me know and I can help you take this that one step further.

You have a good start on this in your LINQ. I'm a little confused about your use of `private` fields in the types, but I'm assuming those to be typos, and that your actual code uses `public`, probably properties.

I'll do this as a couple separate methods just to make what I'm doing more clear, but you may want to bring them together in the interest of performance. Particularly since I order the collection twice, effectively.

This method groups and sorts the data, based on the first day of their year-month set. Note that you can actually perform a grouping on an anonymous type. Sorting doesn't work on the anonymous object itself, as you noted, but it does work on its properties.

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Bar>> GroupIntoMonths(IEnumerable<Bar> bars)
{
    return bars.GroupBy(c => new { c.StockDate.Year, c.StockDate.Month })
               .OrderByDescending(c => c.Key.Year)
               .ThenByDescending(c => c.Key.Month);
}
```

The choice is yours whether you prefer to group on an instantiated `DateTime` object with a date set of one, or what I've done here. I don't touch the `Key` property again, so I was fine effectively losing track of it after I left the method. Other implementations might drive you to make a different decision on that.

Once you've got that, it's a matter of converting an `IEnumerable<Bar>` into a single `Bar` that summarizes the whole period.

```
public IEnumerable<Bar> GroupIntoBars(IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, Bar>> groups)
{
    return groups.Select(GetBar);
}
public Bar GetBar(IEnumerable<Bar> bars)
{
    Bar ret = new Bar();

    Bar last = null;
    int index = -1;
    foreach(var v in bars.OrderBy(c => c.StartingDate))
    {
        index++;

        if(index == 0)
        {
            ret.Open = v.Open;
            ret.StockDate = v.StockDate;
            ret.High = v.High;
            ret.Low = v.Low;
        }
        else
        {
            ret.High = Math.Max(ret.High, v.High);
            ret.Low= Math.Max(ret.Low, v.Low);
        }
        last = v;
    }

    if(last == null) throw new ArgumentException("Collection cannot be empty!");
    ret.Close = last.Close;

    return ret;
}
```

I think that method is pretty straight-forward, but let me know if I can clear anything up.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by multiple properties at once by specifying them in an anonymous object that will be the group key:

```
var monthlyGroup = aBar.OrderBy(bar => bar.stockDate)
                       .GroupBy(bar => new { Year = bar.stockDate.Year, Month = bar.stockDate.Month })
                        //create bars from groups
                       .Select(g => new bar()
                            {
                                open = g.First().open,
                                high = g.Max(b => b.high),
                                low = g.Min(b => b.low),
                                close = g.Last().close,
                                volume = g.Average(b => b.volume),
                                stockDate = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1)
                            })
                       .ToList();
```

Sorry but I prefer the functions syntax of linq.

I noticed that fields in `bar` class are `private` so they will be inaccessible. However, I assume that you have properties for each field.
In that case you will have to replace field names with property names in the code above.